# jquery date validation in firefox does not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I have using mvc4 when i am save click event in firefox and IE 9 given me false value from validation but in chrome working correct.

Date format must be set `dd M y` (21 Jun 13) please do not change date formate.
Why this happend i don't know please give me help for this.

Check edit this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ycgd/2/)

**NOTE : Please Run In Firefox (my version 20.0.1) OR IE 9**

Also i have try different type solution but its does not work for me.

[MVC 4: Date validation error in Firefox, Chrome, Safari - IE ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314253/mvc-4-date-validation-error-in-firefox-chrome-safari-ie-ok)

[The field date must be a date in mvc in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706455/the-field-date-must-be-a-date-in-mvc-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

***Suggestion 1***

- Use `.datepicker("setDate", 'dd M y');` instead of `.datepicker("setDate", "0");`, so your selected date didn't changed.

*More details* you can see on [official library page](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate)

***Suggestion 2***

- Try to avoid use `alert()`. Better use `console.log()`  and debug your code in browser developer console instead of `alert()` method.

*More* about browser console methods you can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console)

```js
$('#date1').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd M y'
}).datepicker("setDate", 'dd M y');

$('#frm-summary-aims').submit(function() {
  console.log($(this).valid());
  return false;
});
```

Comment: an explanation of your code would improve this answer greatly.

Comment: @DrCord made some explanations for my answer